# Get which file doesn't exist with file_exists but using an array

Tags: php, function, web, file-exists

Well,

I have a script, that checks if one of the files in the array exists or not.

But now I don't know how to get the file, from the array that doesn't exist.
Here's an example:

```php
<?php
$files = [
   "user/important.ini",
   "user/really_needed.php"
];

if(file_exists($files) == false) {
   $data = "1";
   $meta = array(
       "file" => ????,
       "error" => "Missing file"
    );

?>
```

So I'd like to "replace" the "????" with the file that doesn't exists, since I don't know how to get this file, it's those question marks.

Is there possible code I could use, to get the file that doesn't exist?

Comment: file_exists takes a string (filename) not an array. You will have to loop over your filenames in $files. In case the check fails for a certain file, you will have its name right there in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_exists()` expects a file name and if you use an array (as you currently do) you should get a warning...

```
Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
```

This assumes that you want all of the files that don't exist and keeps a list of the failures.  It uses `foreach()` over the array and tests each item, adding it to the list if it doesn't exist using `$meta[]` (don't forget to initialise this array before the loop) ...

```
$files = [
        "user/important.ini",
        "user/really_needed.php"
];
$meta = [];
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    if(file_exists($file) == false) {
        $data = "1";
        $meta[] = array(
                "file" => $file,
                "error" => "Missing file"
        );
    }
}

print_r($meta);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the files to check if they exist is one way this could be done. I suggest using a `foreach` loop here.

```php
<?php
$files = [
   "user/important.ini",
   "user/really_needed.php"
];

$meta = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
   if(!file_exists($file) {
      $data = "1";
      $meta[] = array(
         "file" => $file,
         "error" => "Missing file"
      );
?>
```

Comment: There is an error in your code. $meta will only hold the last missing file. Add [] to the variable name.

Comment: Right, forgot he was checking multiple files. Thanks for the heads up <3